# mongoose Getting a nested field value from a queried document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to Node js and Mongoose and I am stuck with this one query.

```
exports.getIndividual=(matchId,phone)=>
 new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
 var e="matchPersonal.m"+matchId+".bo1";
 query={};
 query[e]=1;

 var quer=usersc.findOne({phone:"8989898980"}).select(query);
 quer.exec(function (err, matc) { 

 var m=matc.toObject();

 console.log('',m);
```

When I Run this query I get on my console this thing

```
        {matchPersonal:{m1:{bo1:3}}}
```

But I just need 3 as my output and I cant use dot operator to read the object properties directly because

```
   var b=matchPersonal.m+matchId.bo1
```

doesnt work as '+' cant be used here so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var mNum = m+matchId;
var b=matchPersonal[mNum].bo1
```

Because you can select properties with dot and with brackets, but brackets also can be used with variables.

Comment: Doesn't work,  says m1 that is m+matchId is undefined but if i make it like matchPersonal.m1.bo1 i get 3 my output so its also not a problem with my schema

Comment: Thanks Its working, after I cleaned my cache and also with mNum="m" +matchId because without it m would be undefined.